# Use ConEmu to run SQL in Notepad++

Tags: oracle, notepad++, sqlplus, toad, conemu

I use Notepad++ every day, and love it endlessly. The only thing I wish it could do that it can't out of the box is run SQL on a DB.

I use ConEmu to run SQLPlus when I need a command line Oracle environment, and Toad for everything else. So what I end up needing to do is either copy my code from N++ and paste it in ConEmu, or Toad. I wish I could just open the "Run" menu in N++, and have a console pop up that runs the code in ConEmu with SQLPlus.

There is [THIS](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/b/weblog/archive/2013/08/21/using-notepad-to-execute-oracle-sql) tutorial on how to set up SQLPlus for N++, but I would prefer ConEmu. Is there any way I could modify the code given in that tutorial to use ConEmu instead, or is my thinking all wrong here?

Code in tutorial:

```
set ORA_USER=bert
set ORA_PASS=bert1234
set ORA_SID= ORCL
npp_save
cmd /c copy /y "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(FILE_NAME)" "$(SYS.TEMP)\$(FILE_NAME)" >nul 2>&1
cmd /c echo. >> "$(SYS.TEMP)\$(FILE_NAME)"
cmd /c echo exit >> "$(SYS.TEMP)\$(FILE_NAME)"
sqlplus -l $(ORA_USER)/$(ORA_PASS)@$(ORA_SID) @"$(SYS.TEMP)\$(FILE_NAME)"
```

If what I'm saying makes no sense, is there a way to use Toad's "Data Grid" as a console in Notepad++?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: So what is your problem? Why not simply change `sqlplus` to `ConEmu - cmd sqlplus`?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Toad? If you're in Toad why not use Toad Script Runner? Look at the Execute as Script button on the Editor's toolbar. There's a small dropdown beside it. Click that and you can send your script to Toad Script Runner or SQL*Plus. Toad Script Runner is a GUI application that will execute your script and give you the grid control. Most users use these "Send to" methods so that Toad is freed up for other work.

Comment: I wish I could do this, but I get an error that says, "This version of Quest ScriptRunner has expired. You must download a new version before proceeding." I'm on my work computer, so I'm limited in what I'm able to do.

Comment: That should not expire. What version of Toad are you using? Is it a paid commercial copy, trial, freeware, other?

Comment: Ok, so to answer my own question I was informed that this was a bug with older releases of Toad (9.7-10.1). There's a new download of Quest Script Runner to fix the bug. You can download it from here... https://support.software.dell.com/Download-Install-Detail/3215668?fID=3215668&pr=Toad%20for%20Oracle